# Does the Cordova Nativestorage plugin work in Xcode emulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova-plugins, cordova-nativestorage

I am updating a Cordova app to use Native Storage over Local Storage. The app will build in Xcode but the Native Storage does not Get and Set values (set items are returned as 'undefined'). No errors are being thrown in the Xcode console; I am calling NativeStorage after onDeviceReady.

I'm using: 
a MacBook pro with High Sierra v10.13.6,
Xcode v10.1,
Cordova v8.0.0,
Cordova iOS v4.5.5

Should I expect NativeStorage to work in the Xcode Emulator? 
Is this a potential compatibility/versioning issue with Cordova 8.0.0? I am in the process of producing a build to test NativeStorage directly on an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeStorage needs to be called as window.NativeStorage.setItem(...), this has solved the problem.